# Retrieve only non-duplicate elements from a list

Tags: python, unique

What is the best option to retrieve only non-duplicate elements from a Python list? Say I have the following list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would like to retrieve the following:

```
lst = [1, 4]
```

(`2` and `3` are not unique in that list, so they don't get retrieved)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a breeze with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [x for x in lst if lst.count(x) == 1]
[1, 4]
>>>
```

Also, I recommend that you do not name a variable `list`--it overshadows the built-in.

Comment: Changed the variable name. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This works, but be warned that preformance will degrade quickly as the list grows larger due to nested loops (`count` is implemented as a loop).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get counts of items.  Combine with a list comprehension to keep only those that have a count of one.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [item for item, count in Counter(lst).items() if count == 1]
[1, 4]
```